# How to make an "All" variable in grafana with bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grafana

I need to make variables in a Grafana dashboard which has for source a Google Big Query table.

However, I also want an "All" option for when the filter is not needed. To do so, I made a "custom all variable" which has the same name as the column name. That way it translate to "where column=column" when the "all" option is selected.

[image: My setup for my grafana variable]

[image: How I add the filter to my graphs]

But! I just saw that column=column actually filters the data, as it remove the cases where column is null.

So my question is the following :
How can I make an "All" option that doesn't filter anything when selected ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like *Jan Garaj* already suggested, you can use the custom all value.

I've changed mine to **IN** to allow the multiple value flag as well

[image: Grafana Variables]

```
'%') OR (products.name IS NULL
```

This will escape the **IN** clause and add an additional **OR** Operator for your **IS NULL** check.

HINT: Use the the Query Inspector to see what *Grafana* will send to BigQuery after resolving the variables.

[image: Query]

Answer (score 1):

General SQL recommendation (it may be implemented differently in Google Big Query):

Use `Custom all value`, which will have wildchar meaning, e.g. `%`
Then use the condition with operator, which is working with that wildchar (not just simple `column=$variable`), e.g. `column LIKE $variable`. So interpolated SQL query will be `column LIKE '%'`.

You may add also `IS NULL` condition explicitly in the `Custom all value`, e.g `'%' OR column IS NULL` and then query condition `column LIKE ${variable:raw}`. Again this is SQL idea and you have to customize it exactly for Google Big Query.

Comment: But doing so still filters out the cases where column is null, which I want to keep

Comment: @LucaAntoine see update, those are generic SQL recommendations. Test and develop them for the specific Google Big Query case, please! That's not a copy&paste solution!!!!!!!